# How can I make a dropdown menu with no submit button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, dropdown, optionmenu

I have a problem. whenever I create a optionmenu in tkinter, I have to submit its data using a button, but I don't think this is simple enough for the user. Is there a way to get a optionmenu submit its data without the submit button?

I want the dropdown menu to update instantly after the user selects one of the options.

Comment: You can with `combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", combobox_changed)`
 and then updating it in the function  `def combobox_changed(event): `

Comment: What do you mean by “drop-down menu”? An `OptionMenu`? A `Menubutton` with an attached menu? A drop-down from a menu bar or from a right click?

Comment: I meaant an option menu